# Parsing Data using jsonParse

Tags: javascript, json, laravel

My laravel controller is returning this data on the blade view using this command `{{$employees}}`

It gives me:

```
[{"id":"1","name":"june"},{"id":"2","name":"joan"}]
```

In my JavaScript:

```
<script>

var jsonData = $.parseJson('{{$employees}}');

alert(1);

</script>
```

But somehow it's throwing an error because the alert is not displaying.

Whats the workaround on these?

Comment: Are you populating data with ajax?

Comment: Is there an error in the Javascript console?

Comment: Why not just use `var jsonData = {{$employees}};`? I don't know anything about laravel, but that should just output your data as a JavaScript array of objects, ready to use, no parsing necessary...

Comment: Thanks Barmar,  yes it was throwing an error before.   the cause quote was escape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible you need to use the tags that don't escape the data

```
{!! $employees !!}
```

instead of

```
{{ $employees }}
```

Is the example string that you supplied the exact string that's being output in the template. There could also be a ' in the content you are outputting which means it would end the string prematurely.

```
eg json = 'I can**'**t find the error';
```

The above would cause errors as the ' in the word can't would make it think the string ended

Comment: {!! $employees !!} did the trick.   What happen is that " was escape.

Comment: glad i could help!